# updated angular from 7 to 12 version successfully but getting scss warning in theme folder

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular7, angular12

1. assets/themes/sita-rtl.scss - Warning: Css Minimizer Plugin:  > assets/themes/sita-rtl.scss:10:2: warning: Expected identifier but found "."
   10 │   .row {
   ╵   ^
2. assets/themes/Product-themes.scss - Warning: Css Minimizer Plugin:  > assets/themes/Product-themes.scss:4:0: warning: Unexpected "$"
   4 │ $image_folder: "/src/assets/images/";

and lot more like this.

Comment: Would be great if you could add the related SCSS code parts.

Answer (score 0):

In-side angular.json I made the below changes and it worked for me.
Kindly look the below code and make the changes or add the code.

"serve": {
"defaultConfiguration": "development",
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "your project name:build"
},
"configurations": {
"development": {
"browserTarget": "your project name:build:development"
},
"production": {
"browserTarget": "your project name:build:production"
}
}
},